# Windows Phone 8.1 Unable to use DataSet for Database Functions

Tags: c#, azure, dataset, windows-phone-8.1

I had previously used `DataSet` in ASP.NET websites and I am currently trying to use `DataSet` in my WP8.1 app but I am unable to do so. Am I missing a reference or is `DataSet` not available / applicable in WP8.1?
I am currently using an `Azure Database`.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) (see Platforms at the bottom), it is not available on Windows Phone. Like most System.Data classes are not.